# Best way in JavaScript to determine whether elements of an array are in progression?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

What I mean is that for a given array `A`, we have

```
A[1] - A[0] = A[2] - A[1] = A[3] - A[2] = ... = A[A.length-1] - A[A.length-2]
```

A basic function I have come up with is

```
function IsProgression ( arr ) 
{
    if ( arr.length < 2 ) return true; // define that there is a progression if the array is empty or has one element
    var diff = arr[1] - arr[0]; 
    for ( var k = 2; k < arr.length; ++k ) 
    {
         if ( (arr[k] - arr[k-1]) != diff ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

but I'm wondering whether the standard JavaScript library has a more compact and/or efficient way of doing this, or if there's a fancier way in general.

Comment: i think yours' correct. you have early termination; stop when found sth unfit and there is no way to make it better than O(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, standard JS library does not have anything related to progressions and your approach is absolutely correct.

To check that you have a progression you need to verify that all the differences `A[n+1] - A[n]` are the same (for geometric that all the divisions are the same). You have done that and you have checked a special case. There is no way to make it faster than `O(n)` because you at least have to read all the elements.

Comment: Agreed. You presented the most algorithmically efficient way to do it. There _might_ be a more succinct way using plug-in libraries that provide more advanced array operations (e.g. the equivalent of the ruby-esque `a.each_slice(2).to_a.map { |x| x[1] - x[0] }.uniq.size == 1`), but these would clearly be less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `reduce` function but your version would exit earlier for non-progressions.

```js
function isProgression(a){
  return a.length < 2 ? 1 : a.reduce( 
    (prev,curr,i) => i == 1 ? true : prev & (a[i] - a[i-1] == a[1] - a[0]) 
  );
}
```